# How to make JS function faster/reduce complexity 0(n)/more efficient

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on some challenges on HackerRank and I am having some troubles with making functions faster/more efficient so that it does not timeout during the submit process. It usually times out for really large inputs (ex: string length of 1000 or more) with the number of loops I am using to get the function working. I know the loops make the complexity 0(n * n) or 0(n * n * n). I understand why the function is timing out because of the above complexity issue but I am not sure of how to make the function more efficient in order to handle larger inputs. I am a self-taught coder so please explain any answers thoroughly and simply so I can learn. Thanks!

Here is an example problem:

A string is said to be a special palindromic string if either of two conditions is met:

- All of the characters are the same, e.g. aaa.
- All characters except the middle one are the same, e.g. aadaa. (acdca will not satisfy this rule but aadaa will)

A special palindromic substring is any substring of a string which meets one of those criteria. Given a string, determine how many special palindromic substrings can be formed from it.

For example, given the string s = mnonopoo, we have the following special palindromic substrings:

- m, n, o, n, o, p, o, o
- oo
- non, ono, opo

Function Description

Complete the substrCount function in the editor below. It should return an integer representing the number of special palindromic substrings that can be formed from the given string.
substrCount has the following parameter(s):

- n: an integer, the length of string s
- s: a string

```js
function substrCount(n, s) {
    //if each letter is its own palindrome then can start with length for count
    let count = n;
    //space used to get the right string slices
    let space = 1;
    //so we only get full strings with the split and no duplicates
    let numberToCount = n;
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
            //slice the string into the different sections for testing if palindrome
            let str = s.slice(j, j+space);
            if(numberToCount > 0){
                //if it is an even length the all characters must be the same
                if(str.length % 2 === 0){
                    let split = str.split('');
                    let matches = 0;
                    for(let k = 0; k < split.length; k++){
                        if(split[k] === split[k+1]){
                            matches++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(matches === split.length -1){
                        count++;
                    }
                //if it is not even then we must check that all characters on either side
                //of the middle are all the same
                } else {
                    if(str.length > 1){
                        let splitMid = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
                        let firstHalf = str.slice(0, splitMid);
                        let lastHalf = str.slice(splitMid+1, str.length);
                        if(firstHalf === lastHalf){
                            if(str.length === 3){
                                count++;
                            } else {
                                let sNew = firstHalf + lastHalf;
                                let split = sNew.split('');
                                let matches = 0;
                                for(let k = 0; k < split.length; k++){
                                    if(split[k] === split[k+1]){
                                       matches++;
                                    }
                                 }
                                 if(matches === split.length -1){
                                    count++;
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            numberToCount--;
        }
        numberToCount = n-space;
        space++;
    }
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: i will enhance it for you to the optimal timing , hold on and allow me few time

Answer (score 0):

i came up with a solution that i think is not too complex in terms of performance(one loop and a recursion at a time)

steps

- split string and insert it into an array
- check first for even pairs into a recursion
- next check for odd pairs again into a recursion
- check that the values inserted to final array are unique(not unique only for single chars)

please let me know if this is the correct solution or we can speed it up

```js
const stirng = "mnonopoo";

const str = stirng.split("");
let finalArray = [];

str.forEach((x, index) => {
  if (str[index] === str[index + 1]) {
    checkEven(str, index, 1)
  }
  if (str[index - 1] === str[index + 1]) {
    checkOdd(str, index, 0)
  }
  finalArray.push(x);
})
function checkOdd(str1, index, counter) {
  if (str1[index - counter] === str1[index + counter]) {
    counter++;
    checkOdd(str1, index, counter);
  } else {
    pushUnique(finalArray, str1.slice(index - counter + 1, index + counter).join(""));
    return str1.slice(index - counter, index + counter).join("")
  }
}

function checkEven(str1, index, counter) {
  if (str1[index] === str1[index + counter]) {
    counter++;
    checkEven(str1, index, counter);

  } else {
    pushUnique(finalArray, str1.slice(index, index + counter).join(""));
    return;
  }
}
function pushUnique(array, value) {
  if (array.indexOf(value) === -1) {
    array.push(value);
  }
}
console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your only looking for special palindromes, and not all palindromes, that makes reducing complexity a bit easier, but even then, there will be some special cases, like "abababababababa....". No way I can see to reduce the complexity of that one too far.

I'd approach this like so. Start by grouping all the repeating numbers. I'm not sure of the best way to do that, but I'm thinking maybe create an array of objects, with object properties of count and letter.

Start with your totalCount at 0.

Then, select all objects with a count of 1, and check the objects to the left and right of them, and if they have the same letter value, take the MAX count, and add that value + 1 to your totalCount (the +1 being to account for the single letter by itself). If the letter values on either side do not match, just add 1 (to account for the letter by itself).

That handles all the odd number palindromes. Now to handle the even number palindromes.

Select all the objects with a count > 1, and take their count value and add the series from 1-count to the totalCount. The formula for this is (count/2)*(1+count). 
Example:
In the string you have a run of 4 A's. There are the special palindromes (a, a, a, a, aa, aa, aa, aaa, aaa, aaaa) in that, for a total of 10. (4/2)*(1+4)=10.

I don't know how much that will reduce your processing time, but I believe it should reduce it some.